# Regarding usage of httparty

Tags: ruby, httparty

I am using httparty module, but there are some things I don't understand.

I am calling `Coursera.for "python"`. The Coursera class does `include HTTParty` rather than `extend HTTParty` so why is a new instance of the Coursera class not needed? Please help me understand this.

There is code - it is working but I'm not clear how

```
require 'httparty'

require 'pp'

class Coursera

   include HTTParty

   base_uri 'https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses'

   default_params fields: "smallIcon,shortDescription",q: "search"

   format (:json)

   def self.for term
      get("",query: {query:term})["elements"]

   end 

end


pp Coursera.for "python"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HTTParty` module has an [included](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb#L20) hook that extends the class you include into with `HTTParty::ClassMethods`. Among other things, this adds the `get` method.